# Find Galois Group of $4x^4+5x^3-9$ over $\mathbb{Q}$

Tags: polynomials, galois-theory, galois-extensions

I proceeded as follow: 
first of all i noticed that $4x^4+5x^3-9$=$(x-1)*(4x^3+9x^2+9x+9)$. So the polynomial has the same galois group of $(4x^3+9x^2+9x+9)$ which is a cubic so it should be either $A_3$ or $S_3$. (Am i wrong? why it has to be one of this two?).
Then i evaluated the discriminant that seems to be negative, and i think the group is $S_3$, but i'm doing this without having truly understood the reason..

Comment: Is the cubic irreducible?

Comment: Why do you think it should be $A_3$ or $S_3$? Is it something you've just seen in some example?

Comment: @Ennar because i think that since the polynomial has degree n his galois group should be a transitive subgroup of $S_3$ and the only one are those two

Comment: @LordSharktheUnknown yes it is

Comment: Using SAGE  with $P(x)=4 x^3+9 x^2+9 x+9$ I got "PARI group [6, -1, 2, "S3"] of degree 3" BTW, great piece of software even if the learning curve is quite logarithmic...

Comment: Alright, Michele. Now, how many real roots does the polynomial have?

Comment: @Ennar  the cubic only one

Comment: @Raffaele i've never heard of this software before

Comment: If $\alpha$ is the only real root of the cubic, what can you say about $\mathbb Q[\alpha]$? Specifically, what's the degree and can it be the splitting field of the cubic?

Comment: the degree should be 3, because the minimal polynomial has degree 3, but we have to add also something with the imaginary unit

Comment: So, what can you conclude about the order of the Galois group?

Comment: That is should be bigger than 3, hence the only option is $S_3$. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

Suppose $f(x) \in \mathbb{Q}[x]$ is a monic irreducible polynomial of degree $d$, and let $\alpha_1, \alpha_2, \cdots, \alpha_d$ denote its roots in $\overline{\mathbb{Q}}$. Consider the product $$P := \prod_{i < j} (\alpha_i - \alpha_j)$$ Note that $P^2$ is the discriminant of $f$.

If an element $\sigma \in \text{Gal}(f) \subset S_{d}$ has $\sigma \in A_d$, then $\sigma(P) = P$, since $\sigma$ can be decomposed into an even number of transpositions. Thus, if $\text{Gal}(f) \subset A_d$, then $\sigma(P) = P$ for all $\sigma \in \text{Gal}(f)$, hence $P \in \mathbb{Q}$. In particular, the discriminant $P^2$ must be a *rational square*.

**Lemma:** If $\text{Gal}(f) \subset A_d$, then the discriminant of $f$ must be a rational square.

Now, let $f(x) = 4x^3 +9x^2 + 9x + 9$. To compute the discriminant, it suffices to compute the discriminant of $f(x+a)$ for any $a\in \mathbb{Q}$ (translating roots does not change the discriminant).

Note that $f(x+3/4) = 4x^3 + (9/4)x + 45/8$, i.e. by translating we have "dampened" the $x^2$ term. Now, we compute the discriminant of $f/4$ to be $-13851/256$, which is certainly **not** a rational square.

Thus, $\text{Gal}(f) = S_3$.

Comment: Did you check that the cubic is irreducible?

Comment: It is irreducible since e.g. it is irreducible over $\mathbb{F}_2$.

Comment: The polynomial $p(x)=2x^3+3x^2+3x+1$ is irreducible over $\Bbb{F}_2$ in the same sense. Yet
$$p(x)=(2x+1)(x^2+x+1).$$
Reduction modulo a prime $p$ is a useful test, but we cannot conclude anything, if the leading coefficient is divisible by $p$.

Comment: Oh right, good point. It is still irreducible, though: since cubic, it would have to have a rational root, which it doesn't by plugging in the possibilities from the rational root theorem.

Comment: Correct. A nice recovery :-)

Comment: @SameerKailasa thank you for your answer. when you say "hence $P \in \mathbb{Q}$ " it is because Q is the fixed field of the galois group, and since $\sigma(P) = P$ for all $\sigma \in \text{Gal}(f)$ P is fixed, is it right?

Comment: @ Michele, yes!